# How can I specify certificate along with username and password in postman?

Tags: postman, ssl-certificate, basic-authentication

I can run `curl` as below to see the server status.

```
curl --cacert http_ca.crt -u elastic https://localhost:9200
```

Can anyone help me to do the same in Postman?

Comment: So your server is using a self signed certificate and you want to avoid an error? You can add your certificate in postman like describe in the docs  https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/certificates/

Comment: As far as I remember you have to use the certificate, and pass the credentials as header manually (`Authorization: Basic [user:pass base64]`)

Comment: @derpirscher The OP needs to send both a certificate + credentials to the webservice

Comment: @Pieterjan I don't think the `--cacert` parameter does send a certificate to the server. According to the docs it's just used to verify the remote server's certificate if it's not in the local machine's trust store. https://curl.se/docs/sslcerts.html

Comment: Ah sorry, I thought he was trying to send an authentication certificate, but it's probably an https certificate